# Is it possible to create Analysis in Oracle BI OBIEE based on only one table?

Tags: oracle, obiee, oracle-bi

Could you explain me please is it possible to create Analysis with only one fact table?
I have one fact table in physical and business layer. It has all columns which I need.

I've tried to create analysis I added months column to horizontal line and sum(sale_num) in vertical line from fact table in analysis and expected to see chart but nothing happened and query which perform OBI doesn't have any group by

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but you have to stick to the ground rules of dimensional analytics: Facts contain measures. Dimensions contain everything else. Facts do NOT contain attributes!

You simply model one logical fact and one logical dimension on your physical table. If you don't do weird things you don't even need to alias the physical table. It becomes the source of both your logical fact and logical dimension.

As long as you stick to the basic rules of dimensional modeling everything will work fine.